# What is the difference between jQuery change and onchange of HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

I have the following HTML code :

```
<select name="test123" id="test123" onchange="testOnchange()">
  <option>Chocolate</option>
  <option>Candy</option>
  <option>Taffy</option>
  <option>Caramel</option>
  <option>Fudge</option>
  <option>Cookie</option>
</select>
<script>
$( "#test123" ).change(function() {
    console.log("change");
  });
function testOnchange() {
    console.log("onchange");
}
</script>
```

If I use JS to set a value for the select like this:

```
$("#test123").val("Candy");
```

why does `testOnchange()` trigger, but jQuery `change` doesn't?

What exactly is the difference between `change` and `onchange`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because you didn't ensured that `<select>` is loaded in dom before binding the `change` event, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/hdpzmt2x/)

and check this [fiddle again](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/hdpzmt2x/1/) when these scripts were wrapped inside `onload` event of the `document`.

Also, if you are setting the value programmatically, you need to trigger the change() event programmatically as well, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396562/change-event-not-firing-after-setting-value-dynamically) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359087/jquery-detecting-programatic-change-event)

```
$( document ).ready( function(){
    $( "#test123" ).change(function () {
        console.log("change");
    });
});

function testOnchange(){
    console.log("onchange")
}
```

Comment: As the script is below element, so the element is available before the event bindind happens, so this doesn't need the doc ready wrapper, although having a doc ready wrapper is best practice.

Comment: @Jai Assuming you are referring to guest271314's answer. In that case the script's positioning will matter which in itself may not be ideal.

Comment: i saw your answer that's why i need to tell you that, doc ready doesn't matter if you put your code below at closing of document and infact your answer doesn't answer the question clearly.

Comment: @Jai "infact your answer doesn't answer the question clearly", Is it? Infact I have explained why questioner's code is not giving him the results he/she is expecting. "Why does testOnchage()trigger, but jquery change not trigger?"

Comment: `$("#test123").val("Candy")` if the value change is done this way. Is it there in your code.

Comment: @Jai got your point. Updating my answer to address this. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

*why does testOnchange() trigger, but jQuery change not?*

This is because `onchange` is an event defined in DOM api but `.change` is from `jQuery`'s event object.

So, although when you apply a change event with jQuery code `$("#test123").val("Candy")` it causes a change event in DOM so the native one is fired only.

In case if you want to trigger the `jQuery`'s `change` event too, then you need to trigger it manually as the other answer suggested. `$("#test123").val("Candy").change();`

Comment: Do you mean `$("#test123").val("Candy")` will trigger `onchange` event and execute `testOnchange` ?

Answer (score 4):

`$("#test123").val("Candy")` does not trigger `onchange` event see, http://jsfiddle.net/j58s9ngv , http://jsfiddle.net/j58s9ngv/1

---

Try calling `.change()` after setting `value` to trigger `onchange` event

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<select name="test123" id="test123" onchange="testOnchange()">
  <option>Chocolate</option>
  <option>Candy</option>
  <option>Taffy</option>
  <option>Caramel</option>
  <option>Fudge</option>
  <option>Cookie</option>
</select>
<script>
$( "#test123" ).change(function () {
    console.log("change");
  });
function testOnchange(){
    console.log("onchange")
}
  $("#test123").val("Candy").change()
</script>
```

Comment: `$("#test123").val("Candy")` this could cause in change event, so why bother to trigger the change event.

Comment: @Jai _"`$("#test123").val("Candy")` this could cause in change event, so why bother to trigger the change event."_ `$("#test123").val("Candy")` does not trigger `onchange` event see, http://jsfiddle.net/j58s9ngv/ , http://jsfiddle.net/j58s9ngv/1/

Comment: That is what i want to mention you should add it in your answer.

Answer (score 4):

`$("#test123").val("Candy")` does not trigger onchange event. I think both same.