# JavaScript input or change event does not work when input value is changed using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events

```
<input id="in" type="text">

<script>
var input = document.getElementById("in");

input.oninput = function () {
    console.log("input");
};

input.onchange = function () {
    console.log("change");
};

setTimeout(function () {
    input.value = "test"
}, 5000);
</script>
```

No events worked.

How to detect input value change using JavaScript?

Comment: Close your quote `<input id="in" type="text">`

Comment: Also make sure the script is in a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Yes, it is all done. Just this example have these mistakes

Comment: JavaScript events do not detect when the value is updated with JavaScript. Basically when you change the value, you should trigger your own custom event.

Comment: You need to trigger change event on event in setTimeout or in setTimeout always take first value or input and match value if different

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686861/input-event-not-working-if-value-is-changed-with-jquery-val-or-javascript