# How to detect value changes of an input jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I am currently using this function to detect for any changes made to an input box in jQuery.

```
$(document).on("input change paste keyup", "input, textarea, select", function(e) {
    //do something
});
```

The problem is that when you change the value of an input through code such as this `$("input").val(currentColorChosen);`, the function does not run.

How do I solve this so that the function can detect all changes made to an input, including value changes made through jQuery.

Comment: direct changes to the value attribute of inputs do not by default trigger any events; you'll probably need to use something like [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to set up a custom listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the one more line after your code:

```
$("input").val(currentColorChosen);
$("input").bind("change");
```

Comment: This will depend on your jQuery lib version

Comment: Currently using the latest version, does this only work for an older version?

Comment: It can be like $("input").on("change"); or $("input").change();

Comment: `.bind('change')` will do nothing. Maybe you meant `.trigger('change')`

Comment: Nope, I didn't mean that. It works for sure. But for this question, I would use $("input").on("change"); as question has it with .on()

Comment: I was able to get this to work by using `$("input").val(value).keyup();`

Comment: Anything you have in your function (input change paste keyup), can be used as you are triggering that function

Answer (score 2):

`$("input").change(function(){console.log("there was a change")})` and I think you can pass the value into it as well, it's a shortcut for `.on( "change", handler )`

More info: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1):

I had just posted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47661820/8892244)

You can try using interval or timeout like this

```
var searchValue = $('#myTextbox').val();

function checkSearchChanged() {
    var currentValue = $('#myTextbox').val();
    if ((currentValue) && currentValue != searchValue && currentValue != '') {
        searchValue = $('#myTextbox').val();
       console.log(searchValue)
    }
    setTimeout(checkSearchChanged, 0.1);
}

$(function () {
    setTimeout(checkSearchChanged, 0.1);
});
```

checkout working plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/iHroB4x0WgwjavPGJ7dH)